# "Save the Blue Whale" or "Save the Blue Whales"?

Tags: grammatical-number

When writing about a breed or species as a whole, which is correct?  I intuitively think the first option sounds better, but I can't put my finger on why that is so.

Comment: The species is 'the blue whale'. Referring to 'the blue whales' suggests that you mean a particular group of them.